# Odd Proxy setting in Microsoft Edge

Tags: proxy, windows-10, trojan, microsoft-edge

Today I encountered odd proxy settings on a user's Windows 10 installation.

Microsoft Edge had the proxy set to:

> use proxyserver

The address field was set to:

> ...os=127.0.0.1:51144

The "port" field was empty.

The "no proxy for" field was set to:

> <-loopback>

I was not able to change the proxy settings.

Is this a trojan of some kind?

Comment: I took a photo, but the fool I was I don't know what was in front of the "os=127.0.0.1:51144"

Comment: Possible. Check what is listening on :51144 .

Comment: You can do @peterh's check as follows: in an admin command prompt, run `netstat -a -b` to find out what ports are open and by what processes.

Comment: This may be some sort of antivirus that tries to scan web traffic.

Comment: Have yoy conected to any kind of WiFi network or VPN? It could be a proxy auto-config file.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the start icon.
2. Click settings.
3. Select Network & Internet.
4. Select Ethernet on the left panel, and click Internet options.
5. When the Internet Properties window opens, click the Connections
   tab.
6. At the bottom of this window, click LAN settings.
7. In the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings window, make sure the Use
   automatic configuration script and Use a proxy server for your LAN
   boxes are not checked, and then click OK.
8. If any settings were changed, click Apply and then OK.
9. Confirm the connection by testing two separate web pages.

[image]

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.